# jQuery error in ASP.NET MVC 3 clientside custom validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a razor view in ASP.NET MVC3 application.

This view has 2 partialviews

1. PartialView1 is strongly typed and binded with the model.
2. PartialView2 is not binded with the model. and this view consists of a collection of checkboxes.

As part of validation atleast one checkbox must be checked to continue with the save.

Following is the jquery code that is giving me error: 
Object does not support this property or method.

Error occuring at this line of code:
$("#form0").validate({ rules: { issueCheckBox: { selectNone: true}} });

Following is the JQuery code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
 <script>
         $.validator.addMethod
            (
                "selectNone",
                function (value, element) {
                    var n = $("input[name='issueCheckBox']:checked").serializeArray();

                    if (n.length < 1) {
                        $("#divIssueCheckBoxError").show();
                        $("#divIssueCheckBoxError").css("color", "red");
                        $("#divIssueCheckBoxError").text("Issue(s) Required. Please select atleast one issue.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#divIssueCheckBoxError").hide();
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                function () { }
           );

           jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#form0").validate({ rules: { issueCheckBox: { selectNone: true}} });
           });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this error only happen in IE9?  If so, it may just be this [jquery ie9 bug](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie-9-beta-displays-error-with-jquery-1-5-min-js) related getElementsByTagName.